# PhantomJS register with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, remote-server, selenium-grid2

I need assistance on registering PhantomJS with Selenium Grid. Based on some approaches I've seen online I implemented it this way:

Grid register

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

PhantomJS

```
phantomjs.exe --webdriver=5555--webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444
```

both cmd started fine but phantomjs is not registered to the grid
[image]

Comment: Have you checked on what interface the selenium-grid-server is registerd? "Localhost" normally resolves as IPv6, but you opted the phantomjs-webdriver to connect to IPv4

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't need Selenium to run the test against phantomjs in webdriver mode.

I don't know wich language and framework are you using. But In behat/mink/phantomjs:

Console:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=8643
```

And in your behat.yml:

```
sessions:
    "Name_of _your_session":
        selenium2:
            wd_host: "http://localhost:8643/wd/hub"
```

The important part here is: wd_host: "http://localhost:8643/wd/hub"
That I'm sure that you can adapt to whatever your system is. You can run the phantomjs from another server and use it only by modifying the IP: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8643/wd/hub"

But you don't need to run the selenium server.

Comment: Which language is this? I'm using .Net (C#) selenium binding. Can you help direct me to where I'm to make the adequate changes?

Comment: Behat/Mink is PHP. I'm not an expert in CSharp but somewhere in your .Net selenium code, there must be a property where you define the URL that hosts the Selenium/Webdriver server. You have to especify there your wd_host URL. In the Selenium documentation:

    IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
                                        DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Yes, I've done that, but still surprise why it's not working. The main problem is that phantomjs is not registering with selenium grid.

Comment: Then I can't help you. I've tried to add the phantomjs to a selenium grid in the past but I didn't find the way. I don't exactly know if with Phantomjs 2.0 it is even possible... The only way I've found is what I say in may response. Without selenium. Sorry.